# Is it possible to build a .net graphql backend and a react with redux frontend?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, react-redux, graphql, apollo-server

The company I am working for has a strong .NET and Microsoft SQL Server backend that I can not change. But we are front-end agnostic. Lately we have been in need of upgrading one of our older apps and I have been looking for solutions. I am looking to use React and Redux as I think they would be the closest to a single code base application between web and native applications. But I need to figure out how I can make sure React can work with .NET and MSS.

So far I have thought about starting with building an ASP.NET Core 2 GraphQL API backend which I know will work with MSS. But I am not sure how that would work with Redux. Here is the article I would start from:

https://fullstackmark.com/post/17/building-a-graphql-api-with-aspnet-core-2-and-entity-framework-core

I have also looked into using Apollo Server, but I am not sure if I would have to add another .Net layer in between Apollo and MSS.

I am just wondering if anyone has any experience in this stack so I can prevent myself from re-inventing the wheel. Any thoughts, suggestions, articles would be helpful and appreciative.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on a project that uses React with TypeScript & GraphQL (among other things) and a C# .NET Backend. We use https://github.com/graphql-dotnet/graphql-dotnet on the server side which works pretty well.

We aren't using Redux, but I don't see why that should be an impediment. Any issues with compatability between GraphQL and Redux shouldn't have anything to do with the server implementation.

There are plenty of Articles on the internet that talk about using both.

https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-redux-apollo-client-state-management-tutorial
https://medium.com/react-weekly/implementing-graphql-in-your-redux-app-dad7acf39e1b
https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/tutorial-how-to-use-graphql-in-your-redux-app-9bf8ebbeb362/

Comment: When it comes to adding realtime events, do you use SignalR?

Comment: No ... we really don't have a need for that in our application (...yet)

Comment: realtime events in GraphQL is handled using Subscription, which under the hood uses WebSocket protocol

Answer (score 0):

I think the question is a bit unclear:

If you claim that your API is `front-end agnostic` then why shouldn't it work with React/Redux Or any other front end technologies?

As For **GraphQL**, In my opinion React Is a decent choice to consume GraphQL APIs as they are both managed by the same company.

For .Net GraphQL Framework I'd Recommend [**Hot Chocolate**](https://hotchocolate.io/). It's an fast growing open source graphQL server framework for **.NET technologies.**

Also As Front-end GraphQL Frameworks [**Relay**](https://relay.dev/) might also be a good choice as it's more powerful than *other graphql clients* but tends to be more complex.

But the main question you should ask yourself is *if you really need to use **GraphQL** at all*. If your API is not too generalized and you know exactly **when and how** each data endpoint is going to be used, then why not go with REST? As you might know GraphQL has it's limitations and is not an universal solution.

Here Are some articles which explain when to use GraphQL over rest and when to do otherwise:

[Rubrik.com: GraphQL vs REST](https://www.rubrik.com/blog/graphql-vs-rest-apis/)

[stablekernel.com: Advantages and disadvantages of GraphQL](https://stablekernel.com/article/advantages-and-disadvantages-of-graphql/)

[dzone.com: when and why to use GraphQL](https://dzone.com/articles/why-and-when-to-use-graphql-1)